# Header Title does not stay centered when back button is present, React Native Android Specific, React Navigation

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

So I'm using [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/en/) 3.0 and React Native. When using headers, the Header Title is centered by default on iOS but he aligned left on Android. I used a fix to center the Header Title for Android and that's fine. When the back button is being displayed, the Header Title is then pushed to the right a little bit. I expected the title to stay centered either way.

So I tried giving the `HeaderLeftContainerStyle` an absolute style so that it won't impact the position of the title but it's not working as expected.

Any recommendations?

Here's what some of the code looks like:

```
const MainCommsStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    ShowMessages: {
      screen: connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps,
      )(MessageScreen),
    },
    ChatWindow: DetailStack,
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: 'COMMS',
      headerTitleStyle: [
        baseStyles.whiteHeaderText,
        {
          alignSelf: 'center',
          textAlign: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          flex: 1,
          textAlignVertical: 'center',
        },
      ],
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: colors.vGreen,
      },
      headerBackImage: <BackButton />,
      headerBackTitle: null,
      headerLeftContainerStyle: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 10,
      },
      headerLayoutPreset: 'center',
    },
  },
);
const CommsStack = createAppContainer(MainCommsStack);
```

Screenshots:
[image: Centered, no back button]
No Back Button, looking centered :)

[image]
Now with Back Button, not centered :(

Comment: Have you tried making the button position absolute instead?

Comment: No but I attempted a different solution and fixed it. Check out my answer and thanks for responding :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Within the `Header.js` file being used by React Navigation I found these lines of code:

```
// These can be adjusted by using headerTitleContainerStyle on navigationOptions
const TITLE_OFFSET_CENTER_ALIGN = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 70 : 56;
const TITLE_OFFSET_LEFT_ALIGN = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 20 : 56;
```

I changed the `TITLE_OFFSET_LEFT_ALIGN` to `0` and got what I wanted. Also, the comment mentions that if you can use `headerTitleContainerStyle` to manipulate it. So in my code I did this:

```
defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: 'COMMS',
      headerTitleStyle: [
        baseStyles.whiteHeaderText,
        {
          flex: 1,
          textAlign: 'center',
        },
      ],
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: colors.vinderGreen,
      },
      headerBackImage: <BackButton />,
      headerBackTitle: null,
      headerTitleContainerStyle: {
        left: 0, // THIS RIGHT HERE
      },
      headerLayoutPreset: 'center',
    },
```

and it's all good :D

Answer (score 2):

If you have the back button on the left and a centered title, just add an empty view to the right:

```
{
  headerTitle: 'COMMS',
  headerRight: <View/>,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone needs the latest solution. Use this property:

```
headerTitleAlign: 'center',
```

Do not center the text within the **headerTitleStyle** property.

Here's the documentation:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headertitlealign

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant of Dres solution. If you know the dimensions of your content (in my case I had an image). You can use the half 'n half-calculation.

```
const DEVICE_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('screen').width;
const LOGOTYPE_WIDTH = 80;
const TITLE_OFFSET_CENTER_ALIGN = DEVICE_WIDTH / 2 - LOGOTYPE_WIDTH / 2;
```

And then put the offset in:

```
 headerTitleContainerStyle: {
    left: TITLE_OFFSET_CENTER_ALIGN, // THIS RIGHT HERE
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

In react-navigation v5

Just add this on the screens that have a back button.

```
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => <View/>,
    });
  }, [navigation]);
```